# How to weight items in a fuzzy search

Tags: javascript, ranking, fuzzy-search, fuse.js

Using [Fuse.js](http://fusejs.io/), I need to weight individual item for a better ranking in search results. For instance, how do I make sure "Paris France" has the biggest score for a "Paris" query with the data below?

```
places = [{
  name: 'Paris, France'
  weigth: 10
},{
  name: 'Paris, Ontario'
  weigth: 2
},
{
  name: 'Paris, Texas'
  weigth: 1
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there are no methods built into Fuse.js to do this. The `weight` property is meant to be applied to properties which are being searched (in the `options` object), rather than to the object that is being searched (as seen in the example [here](http://fusejs.io/#weighted-search).

What I might suggest is writing a function to sort this yourself. So once you get your results array back, after the search, perform an `Array.sort()` on it yourself (documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)).

For example...

```js
//Your places object
var places = [
  {
    name: 'Paris, Texas',
    weight: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Paris, France',
    weight: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Paris, Texas',
    weight: 1
  }
];

//Your search options
var options = {
  keys: [
    "name"
  ]
};
var fuse = new Fuse(places, options); // "list" is the item array
var result = fuse.search("Paris");

//Once you have got this result, perform your own sort on it:

result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.weight - a.weight;
});

console.log('Your sorted results:');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.1.0/fuse.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doing a second sort is a good patch. I also experimented with the quality score returned by Fuse and using the weights as multipliers. Otherwise, the second sort might end up surfacing otherwise poor matches.